# Solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 16$ when $x_i$ is odd or even (but not both)

Tags: combinatorics

How do I solve $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 16$ when $x_i$ is:

1.even

2.odd

I can solve it by bruteforcing it, but I don't really like it that way + it wouldn't work with more complex equations.

Any hints?

Comment: Can $x_1=x_2$ ?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yeah. there are no other restrictions

Comment: If all $x_i$ are even, then they can be expressed as $x_i = 2k_i$ for some $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, your problem will be a matter of finding $k_i$ such that their sum is 8. If all $x_i$ are odd, then they can be expressed as $x_i = 2k_i + 1$ for some $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, your problem will be a matter of finding $k_i$ such that their sum is 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

For the even case, let $x_i=2y_i$, so now you have to solve $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=8$.

For the odd case, let $x_i=2y_i+1$, so now you have to solve $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=6$.

Comment: Thanks. way simpler than I thought.

Comment: Great, glad it was helpful! Please accept an answer with the checkmark to the left (either my answer or another one) so the question is marked as 'resolved' in the system.

Answer (score 2):

In general, assume an equation of the form

$$\sum_{i=1}^m x_i = N$$

If all $x_i$ are even then there exists $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x_i = 2k_i$. Substitution yields

$$\sum_{i=1}^m 2k_i = N$$
 $$2\sum_{i=1}^m k_i = N$$
 $$\sum_{i=1}^m k_i = \dfrac{N}{2}$$
The problem has been reduced to a form as shown above. 
If all $x_i$ are odd then there exists $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x_i = 2k_i + 1$. Substitution yields
$$\sum_{i=1}^m (2k_i + 1) = N$$
 $$m +2\sum_{i=1}^m k_i = N$$
 $$\sum_{i=1}^m k_i = \dfrac{N-m}{2}$$
The problem has been reduced to a form as shown above. Without extra constraints on $x_i$ this is as far as we can go.